# Get length of current line

Tags: vim

I'm trying to add an indicator in my statusline for the total length of the line (not just the cursor column position, which can be shown with `%c`). How do I do this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To get the contents of a line as a string, use `getline(<line number>)`.

To get the contents of the current line as a string, you can use `getline(".")`.

To get the length of a string, you can use `strlen(<string>)`.

Putting it all together, we get `strlen(getline("."))`. To add it to your statusline, simply:

```
statusline += "%{strwidth(getline('.'))}"
```

or for vim-airline (what I use)

```
" can be any section; this is for section z (right hand side)
let g:airline_section_z = "%{strlen(getline('.'))}"
```

Comment: Beware, strlen count bytes, not the actual number of characters. You'll to use functions like strwidth to obtain the actual length of the line.

Comment: Just note that `strdisplaywidth` seems to be align with `%v`.